# Remote connection to mysql2 using ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, rake, mysql2

I m trying to connect to mysql2 that is installed in a VM1 from another VM2.
vm2 connect to vm1 using ssh and the coonnection wroks.
Howerver when i try to connect to mysql i get this error:

```
No connection. Check your internet connection.
```

my config.yaml file contains this:

```
# SQL connection
:adapter: mysql2
:database: project
:username: bochra
:password: 'password'
:host: ip_@_VM1
```

and a part of my Rakefile looks like this:

```
config = YAML.load(File.open('config.yaml'))
puts 'Clearing the database of all data.'
  begin
    client = Mysql2::Client.new(config)
    client.query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Employees')
    client.query('CREATE TABLE Employees(id INT, age INT, salary TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))')

  rescue
    ErrorHandler.new.show_error :no_connection
  end
```

Comment: Firewall rules?

Comment: when i run sudo iptables -L in the client(VM2) there r no rulles, but when i try sudo iptables -L in the server (vm1) it doesn't give me the permession because i have created a user (ubuntu) for the client in order to establish ssh connection. So this user ubuntu is not in the sudoers file.

Comment: I'm just saying that `ssh` and `mysql` may be subject to different rules. Use a tool like `nmap` to see if the port is even open.

Comment: @Bochra You are silencing the actual exception. Remove `rescue` block to get a more detailed error.

Comment: @Bartosz this what i get when i remove the rescue block:rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.28' (111)
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:87:in `connect'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:87:in `initialize'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have a default installation of MySQL on my default Ubuntu  I haven't really changed any settings after install.
In the default installation the bind address was set to 127.0.0.1 so i commented it. After that i got another errot it said:
`Mysql2::Error: Host 'xxxxxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`. So from the server (VM1) i granted privelleges to my user (bochra) using this:

```
CREATE USER 'bochra'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'bochra'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION; and that worked fine for me
```